# Are there any podcast channel about OSX and/or IOS programming?

Tags: ios, macos, podcast

I'm looking for podcasts about IOS/OSX development, could you suggest some good resources ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out iTunes University. iTunes U in the iTunes Store. Search for iOS Development and you'll find a lot :) mostly for free.

Answer (score 4):

I am the host for a podcast on iOS development by iOS developers.  The podcast is called iOhYes.  You can find us on iTunes and via our website at http://iOhYesPodcast.com. We talk about the latest news affecting iOS developers and other discussions relevant to iOS developers.

Answer (score 2):

For regular updates about iOS/MacOS/Web development, you can listen to the weekly podcast **Build & Analyze** hosted by Marco Arment (creator of Instapaper). It's not too technical but it's like the news of being an Apple-platform developer. Always awesome.

Comment: Yeah! I often listen to Arment and Dan Benjami they have a really cool conversations :), but i'm looking for something more technical if possible.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this list of podcasts for iOS developers
https://www.codefellows.org/blogs/top-5-podcasts-for-ios-developers

Answer (score 0):

I host one for beginners named [Springboard](http://springboardshow.com) if anyone is interested.